# why does rclpy timer have no update method and stored in ns?

Tags: ros, ros2, timer, update, rclpy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

using [rclpy timer](https://docs.ros2.org/foxy/api/rclpy/api/timers.html) there does not appear to be any method for updating the timer period/interval there is simply a timer_period_ns variable which can be changed but it feels a bit off, especially the whole multiply by a million part. Is there a reason it is this way?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392928/why-does-rclpy-timer-have-no-update-method-and-stored-in-ns?/) by [masynthetic](https://answers.ros.org/users/61140/masynthetic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2021-12-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @masynthetic

To better answer your question, let's step back a little to review the following concepts. Source: [ROS2 Documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Concepts/About-Executors.html?highlight=timer)

**Executors**:

> An Executor uses one or more threads
> of the underlying operating system to
> invoke the callbacks of subscriptions,
> timers, service servers, action
> servers, etc. on incoming messages and
> events. The explicit Executor class
> (in executor.hpp in rclcpp, in
> executors.py in rclpy, or in
> executor.h in rclc) provides more
> control over execution management than
> the spin mechanism in ROS 1, although
> the basic API is very similar.

**Scheduling**

> If the processing time of the
> callbacks is shorter than the period
> with which messages and events occur,
> the Executor basically processes them
> in FIFO order. However, if the
> processing time of some callbacks is
> longer, messages and events will be
> queued on the lower layers of the
> stack. The wait set mechanism reports
> only very little information about
> these queues to the Executor. In
> detail, it only reports whether there
> are any messages for a certain topic
> or not. The Executor uses this
> information to process the messages
> (including services and actions) in a
> round-robin fashion - but not in FIFO
> order. In addition, **it prioritizes all
> timer events over the messages**. The
> following flow diagram visualizes this
> scheduling semantics.

[image: image description]

There is a great [presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sz-nllmtcc8&t=644s) by Ralph Lange that explains Executor Design as well. And one key principle, **Timers overrule everything** as there may be conflicting priorities in real time with the other executors.

Given these 2 concepts of Executors and Scheduling, we also need to appreciate that

> "ROS multiplexes independent message
> handlers onto shared threads using
> custom scheduling policies.
> Consequently, applications running on
> top of ROS are subject to the
> scheduling decisions of the underlying
> operating system and the middleware
> layer, with complex and interdependent
> effects on timing."

**Source**: [Response-Time Analysis of ROS 2 Processing
Chains Under Reservation-Based Schedulingby D. Casini, T. Blaß, I. Lütkebohle, and B. B. Brandenburg](https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2019/10743/pdf/LIPIcs-ECRTS-2019-6.pdf)

Timers can be set in nano-seconds due to the important role they play in Scheduling, thus the need to multiply by a million. Even though your application may not need but the capability is there.

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1